# Highlight Data from Pivot Table Subject to Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

[image: See attached picture]

I want to highlight data pertaining to a particular line in the pivot table subject to certain criteria (here sum of Reco amount = 0).

I am able to insert pivot using VBA but not able to get to the lines and highlight individual lines related to that.

Is it possible to that or is it too far fetched for VBA?

Expected output- Except for 01.08.2022 and 18.08.2022, all the lines will be highlighted in the original data table.

Comment: It might be more direct to scan the original table for dates whose sum is zero.

Comment: I was not able to think about a way to do it from the original data table, that is why I made the pivot table. How do I do it directly from the data table? Please share if you have any idea.

Comment: You can loop over the data and use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to total up the amounts against each unique date: you can then loop again an highlight all dates where the total in the dictionary is zero.  Or if you're not comfortable with VBA use a worksheet formula like `SUMIF()` and some conditional formatting for the zero values.